# How do I use Botan::MemoryRegion?

Tags: c++, botan

Does anyone know how to create an object of type Botan::MemoryRegion for use in this method?

```
BigInt BOTAN_DLL fe1_encrypt(const BigInt& n, const BigInt& X,
                         const SymmetricKey& key,
                         const MemoryRegion<byte>& tweak);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `MemoryVector` and `SecureVector` inherit from `MemoryRegion` and can be used quite similar to `std::vector`.

```
BYTE tweakData[tweakDataLen] = { ... };
MemoryVector<byte> myTweak(tweakData, tweakDataLen);
```

`SecureVector` takes some precautions to prevent the data from spreading around (e.g. overwrite-before-delete and supresses some swap-to-disk scenarios)